# I can't find what is wrong with my code, and I can't upload the image to the server, it seems like I didn't really upload a image even I do so

Tags: php, html, database, forms, file-upload

I am a beginer of php, I write a code that could upload input to the database, but only the image part is not working

here's the code of the move image function(from class.php):

```
function moveimage($temp,$dest){

  if (move_uploaded_file($temp, $dest))
{
  echo "Image moved to folder";
} else {
  echo "Image not moved to folder";


  }

}
```

and here's the other code that links to it(from script.php):

```
<?php
require_once('class.php');

access();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $theme = $_POST['theme'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    if(isset($_FILES['image'])) {

        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $temp= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $dest = '/pra/image/';

        insert($name, $location, $theme, $description, $image);
        moveimage($temp,$dest . $image);
        echo "submit sucess";
    } else {
        insert($name, $location, $theme, $description, null);
        echo "submit sucess without image";
    }
        errorslog();


    

}
?>
<?PHP
```

I add the enctype="multipart/form-data" to my html form, and if I delete the if(isset($_FILES['image'])) part, it would give me a "Notice: Undefined index: image" and "Notice: Trying to access array offset" for these two lines of the code.

```
        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $temp= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
```

I will be appreciate if someone could help me with that.

Comment: Hmm... `if(isset($_FILES['image']))` makes sure that `$_FILES['image']` is not null, but it shouldn't be null in the first place if your code's working correctly.  Can you add your HTML form?

Comment: change "$_FILES['image']['name']" to basename($_FILES['image']['name']), may be that why the image file is not been uploaded. $_FILES['image']['name'] contains full path of client file name.

Comment: it works when I change "$_FILES['image']['name']" to basename($_FILES['image']['name']), but I still didn't get it, like why it's working with the change